# Drawing a figure with concentric circles with text and shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am trying to draw the below given figure. Please help me to plot it in Tikz. I am only able to plot concentric circles. [image: Concentric Cirlces].
I would like to have different colors in between different circles. Also, the text should be along the curve. The arrow in between the two concentric circles does not have to overlap with the circle on the right hand side.

I would be grateful if you could help me in plotting this in Tikz. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\ifCLASSINFOpdf

\else

\fi

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx,tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\title{Practice Tex}


\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} 

  \draw(0,0) circle (0.4cm)
  node[draw=none,sloped,above]{cxvzxcv};    


  \draw(0,0) circle (0.75cm) node[draw=none,sloped,above]{ratio};

  \draw(0,0) circle (1.25cm);
  \node[draw=none,align=center, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.25cm] at (0,2.2) {22};

  \draw(0,0) circle (2cm);
  \node[draw=none,align=center, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.25cm] at (0,3.8) {33333};

  \draw(0,-9) circle (0.4cm);
  \node[draw=none,align=center, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.25cm] at (0,-9) {fsgsdgf};  

  \draw(0,-9) circle (0.75cm);
  \node[draw=none,align=center, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.25cm] at (0,-7.8) {fgdsfg};

  \draw(0,-9) circle (1.25cm) node[midway,sloped] at (0,-9) {dfsdfad};

  \draw(0,-9) circle (2.8cm);
  \node[draw=none,align=center, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.25cm] at (0,-6.4) {dfsdfsd};

  \draw(0,-9) circle (3.2cm);
  \node[draw=none,align=center, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.25cm] at (0,-6) {dfsdfsd};

  \draw(0,-9) circle (3.6cm);
  \node[draw=none,align=center, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.25cm] at (0,-5.6) {sfdsfd};

  \draw(0,-9) circle (4.4cm);
  \node[draw=none,align=center, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.25cm] at (0,-4.8) {sdfsf}; 

  \pgfsetlinewidth{3pt} 
  \draw [-implies][->] (0,-4) -- (0,-4.6);


\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always, some compilable code to see how far have you gone or anything that shows a minimal effort on your side, is welcome. Right now this looks like a “do it for me” question. What is that you don't know? Drawing arrows? Drawing (curved) labels? Coloring the inside of a circle? All of these are already answered here.

Comment: Please remove everything from your code that is not relevant with your problem. That's what "minimal" in [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) means.

Comment: Here is my attempt. I did try to  plot and have text along the curve but I could not get the text along the curve of a circle. Coloring inside the circle is fine for me but how will I have different colors in between different circles? I am very new to Tikz so I am unable to be innovative here. I would be thankful if you could help me with the plot. Thanks!

Comment: I did remove everything that is not needed but have kept the packages and few commented out code which might be required by the person who helps me. Kindly, let me know and I would be happy to trim it down even further. Thanks again !

Comment: A lot of packages loaded here are irrelevant to your problem: `amsmath`, `algpseudocode`, `gnuplottex` `url`, etc.

Comment: Removed as many code lines as I could find out. I will remove more code once I find out.

Comment: I don't understand how your attempt relates to the picture you posted. When I compile your example (trimmed quite a bit), I get the first set of circles above the second and, above that, I get '22' and then a ways above *that*, I get '3333'.

Comment: By the way, you are loading `color` and `tikz` twice. This is likely to lead to confusion at some point, as well as a needlessly complex preamble.

Comment: ok, I will pay attention to your comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this is made with the libraries `decorations.text` and `arrows.meta` together with the correspondent options

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);

\draw (O) circle (2.5);
\draw (O) circle (1.5);
\draw (O) circle (0.5);

\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={Wee}},decorate] (0.6,0) arc (0:180:0.6);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={There is a way?}},decorate] (1.6,0) arc (0:180:1.6);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={Should be here any!}},decorate] (2.6,0) arc (0:180:2.6);

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill=red!30] (O) circle (2.8);
\draw[fill=green!40] (O) circle (2);
\draw[fill=yellow!70] (O) circle (1.2);
\draw[fill=blue!45] (O) circle (0.4);

\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={xxx}},decorate] (0.5,0) arc (0:180:0.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={yyy}},decorate] (1.3,0) arc (0:180:1.3);
%\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={Should be here any!}},decorate] (2.1,0) arc (0:180:2.1);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={Hello, how are you?}},decorate] (2.9,0) arc (0:180:2.9);
\end{scope}
\draw[line width=2mm,>={Triangle[length=3mm,width=5mm]},->] (2.6,0) -- (3.8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

### EDIT

Or you can simplify the code a bit by using *loops* (`\foreach`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\foreach \j in {1,...,3} \draw (O) circle (3.5-\j);
\foreach \k/\text in {0/Should be here any!,1/There is a way?,2/Wee} \draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={\text}},decorate] (2.6-\k,0) arc (0:180:2.6-\k);
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\foreach \k in {1,...,4}\pgfmathparse{12*\k} \draw[fill=red!\pgfmathresult] (O) circle (3.6-0.8*\k);
\foreach \k/\text in {0/{Hello, how are you?},1/,2/yyy,3/xxx} \draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={\text}},decorate] (2.9-0.8*\k,0) arc (0:180:2.9-0.8*\k);
\end{scope}
\draw[line width=2mm,>={Triangle[length=3mm,width=5mm]},->] (2.6,0) -- (3.8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a beginning which demonstrates 2 ways to fill the spaces between the circles and one way to curve text around the circles. One basically fills the circles in reverse order of size so that the fill for smaller circles overrides the fill from earlier circles. The other uses the 'even odd rule' for a single fill between two circles.

The `decorations.text` library is key for fitting the text to the path. There are two main options: `text along path` and `text effects along path`. The first, which I think is simpler to use, is shown in this example.

I've done a couple of other things, here. The first is that I've defined a style to avoid repetition, ensure consistency and make it easier to make changes should you need to. The second is that I've specified a couple of coordinates so that it is easier to move the nests of circles around if you need to. (Just change the specification of `c1` and/or `c2` in one place and all should follow.) I've also updated the arrow to use the newer `arrows.meta` library.

**EDIT:** The code now demonstrates the use of a loop to colour and label the circles for the second set.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    circle type 1/.style={draw=none,align=center, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.25cm},
  ]

  \coordinate (c1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (c2) at (0,-9);

  \path (c1) [draw, fill=red, decoration={text along path, text={Some text along the path}, reverse path}, postaction=decorate] circle (2cm);
  \path (c1) [draw, fill=orange] circle (0.4cm) node [draw=none,sloped,above] {cxvzxcv};
  \path [fill=blue, even odd rule, draw] (c1) circle (0.75cm) node[draw=none,sloped,above]{ratio} (c1) circle (1.25cm);

  \node[circle type 1] at (0,2.2) {22};

  \node[circle type 1] at (0,3.8) {33333};

  \foreach \i / \j [count=\ino] in {4.4cm/sdfsf, 3.6cm/sfdsfd, 3.2cm/dfsdfsd, 2.8cm/dfsdfsd, 1.25cm/dfsdfad, 0.75cm/fgdsfg, 0.4cm/fsgsdgf}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\colmixer}{mod(10*\ino,100)}%
      \path [draw, fill=blue!\colmixer, decoration={text along path, text={\j}, reverse path}, postaction=decorate] (c2) circle (\i);
    }

  \draw [-Implies, line width=3pt] (0,-4) -- (0,-4.6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the first set of concentric circles:

[image: Nested circles]

Here is the second nest of circles coloured using the loop:

[image: Circles coloured by loop]

## Update

In response to the question in comments, if you want the text at the top of the circle, rather than at the right, it is easiest to switch to `arc` construction so that you do not need to guess how far along the path the text should be. (The answer from skpblack uses this approach already.)

This version colours both sets of circles using loops and calculates the position for the arrows using the `calc` library so that the arrow goes into the second set of circles. I've also put that set on the right by adjusting the definition of `c2`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,decorations.text,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    circle type 1/.style={draw=none,align=center, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.25cm},
  ]

  \coordinate (c1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (c2) at (9,0);

  \foreach \i / \j [count=\ino] in {2cm/Some text along the path, 1.25cm/Some more text along another path, 0.75cm/ratio, 0.4cm/cxvzxcv}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\colmixer}{mod(10*\ino,100)}%
      \path [draw, fill=red!\colmixer, decoration={text along path, text={\j}, text align=center, reverse path}, postaction=decorate] (c1) ++(0,-\i) arc (-90:270:\i);
    }

  \foreach \i / \j [count=\ino] in {4.4cm/sdfsf, 3.6cm/sfdsfd, 3.2cm/dfsdfsd, 2.8cm/dfsdfsd, 1.25cm/dfsdfad, 0.75cm/fgdsfg, 0.4cm/fsgsdgf}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\colmixer}{mod(10*\ino,100)}%
      \path [draw, fill=blue!\colmixer, decoration={text along path, text={\j}, text align=center, reverse path}, postaction=decorate] (c2) ++(0,-\i) arc (-90:270:\i);
    }

  \draw [-Implies, line width=3pt] ($(c1)!1/3!(c2)$) -- ($(c1)!2/3!(c2)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: two nests coloured using loops]

## Update II

The question was asked how to move the text inside the relevant circle. Here is one way to do that which involves using a second path with a slightly smaller circle to set the text after the main path has been drawn and filled. Because TeX cannot cope with doing this for the 0.4cm circles, these are excluded using a conditional based on the number of iterations of the loop. This test therefore depends on the number of circles in the nest. For the second set, it is the 7th circle which must be excluded; for the first set, it is the 4th.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,decorations.text,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    circle type 1/.style={draw=none,align=center, font=\scriptsize,text width = 1.25cm},
  ]

  \coordinate (c1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (c2) at (9,0);
  \newlength{\smallercircle}

  \foreach \i / \j [count=\ino] in {2cm/Some text along the path, 1.25cm/Some more text along another path, 0.75cm/ratio, 0.4cm/cxvzxcv}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\colmixer}{mod(10*\ino,100)}%
      \path [draw, fill=red!\colmixer] (c1) ++(0,-\i) arc (270:-90:\i);
      \ifnum\ino<4
        \setlength{\smallercircle}{\i}
        \addtolength{\smallercircle}{-7.5pt}
        \path [decoration={text along path, text={\j}, text align=center, reverse path}, decorate] (c1) ++(0,-\smallercircle) arc (-90:270:\smallercircle);
      \fi
    }

  \foreach \i / \j [count=\ino] in {4.4cm/sdfsf, 3.6cm/sfdsfd, 3.2cm/dfsdfsd, 2.8cm/dfsdfsd, 1.25cm/dfsdfad, 0.75cm/fgdsfg, 0.4cm/fsgsdgf}
    {
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\colmixer}{mod(10*\ino,100)}%
     \path [draw, fill=blue!\colmixer] (c2) ++(0,-\i) arc (-90:270:\i);
     \ifnum\ino<7
       \setlength{\smallercircle}{\i}
       \addtolength{\smallercircle}{-7.5pt}
       \path [decoration={text along path, text={\j}, text align=center, reverse path}, decorate] (c2) ++(0,-\smallercircle) arc (-90:270:\smallercircle);
     \fi
    }

  \draw [-Implies, line width=3pt] ($(c1)!1/3!(c2)$) -- ($(c1)!2/3!(c2)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: text inside the circles]

An alternative method would be to use `text effects along path` rather than `text along path` and to specify the `anchor` of each character as `north`. This would avoid the need to specify the height of the text and avoid the need for a second path. However, I could not make this work and I could not easily figure out why so I used this method instead. Apart from the fact that I could make it work (which may just be my lack of skill with the other text decoration), the advantage of this method is that you should have fewer problems with characters overlapping, something which would be likely with the other method.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very good solution. Please answer one small question, how to place text on the top of the circle instead on the right hand side? Thanks once again !

Comment: The most straightforward way is to use `arc` instead of `circle`. Otherwise you need to figure out how far along the path the text should begin which is no fun.

Comment: @NewUser Please see my updated code but note that skpblack's answer also uses the `arc` construction (and was posted before my update).

Comment: Thanks for the updated code, please explain what is happening here "\draw [-Implies, line width=3pt] ($(c1)!1/3!(c2)$) -- ($(c1)!2/3!(c2)$);" . I tried changing the value "1/3" to something else and the arrow moves around, but how is it getting computed? Thanks again for the updated answer.

Comment: `($(c1)!1/3!(c2)$)` is the coordinate placed in the segment of line between `(c1)` and `(c2)` (i.e `(0,0)` and `(9,0)` in the example) at `1/3` of distance of `(c1)` and `2/3` of `c2` where `1` is the lenght of this segment.

Comment: It is taking 1/3 of the first coordinate and 2/3 of the second (in the first case) and 2/3 of the first coordinate and 1/3 of the second (in the second case). `calc` lets you calculate with coordinates and the `!` syntax is similar to that for colours cf. `blue!33!white` which would mix 1 part blue to 2 parts white. So for `($(c1)!1/3!(c2)$)` if `c1` is at (3,6) and `c2` is at (30,0), you'll get (1+20,2+0) i.e. (21,2).

Comment: @NewUser Forgot to add the tag so you'd get notified. Do our combined explanations make sense?

Comment: Thank you , yes everything makes. One last question, how can I make the text come inside? @cfr

Comment: @NewUser See 'Update II' but note that the text was outside in your original sketch!

Comment: Yes, I agree. The question just popped up in my mind at the last minute. Thanks once again ! @cfr

Answer (score 3):

When I was writing an answer for [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/431257) it was flagged as duplicate.

So here is just for fun a "style only" version.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  hello/.style={
    label={[draw,circle,xscale={1.25},minimum size=14mm+#1*21mm]center:},
    label={[red,yshift=#1*11mm]center:hello}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate[hello/.list={0,1,2,3}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]