# Word inside circle by levels

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is possible do this in latex by tikz? Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Yes my idea is that it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \Y[count=\X from 0] in {word,different,I am a,hello}
{\node (hello\X) at (0,1.2*\X) {\Y};
\draw (0,0) circle ({1.3*\X+1} and {1.1*\X+0.8});}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks!!! one question, how can I write different word in each level? With your code , I just can write one word

Comment: @Vidal I updated the answer. Notice, however, that there are much better possibilities depending on what you precisely want. You may want to make an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) based on what you have, and then ask a question.